# Android text view special characters issue

Tags: android, special-characters, textview

I have a text view in an Android application, this text view's text is populated from an API request, the response of this API is only a text, but this text might have special characters like an apostrophe or any other special character.

The problem is that when the response has special characters the text view only displays that special character and what's after it, **examples:**

When the response is `Capt. Tony's` the text view displays only `'s`.

When the response is `Golf Club` the text view works normally and displays `Golf Club`

When the response is `Café 28` the text view only displays `é 28`

And I know the response is correct because I have tested it too many times.

**CODE OF MY TEXT VIEW:**

**XML**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello world"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

**JAVA**

```
TextView item_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    item_name.setText(item.getTitle());
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Neo how can this question benefit me?

Comment: Make sure you also receive the encoding from API when receiving the text and use it. For HTTP that's mostly in `Content-Type` header of response. You should also request proper encoding, by using correct `Accept-Type`, or `Accept-Charset` headers. E.g. `Accept-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: From Neo link: Font doesn't support this glyph. Since android choose font somehow automatically it choose one which has one kind of glyphs but doesn't have others. So, you need to use font which support them both.

Comment: You can try using your own font from assets, making sure it has support for the required characters.

Comment: @AccessDenied I am using font Lato Light from assets.

Comment: So, do you specify item_name.setTypeFace in your code?

Comment: Have you tried to print title in logcat? Does it show them correctly?

Comment: @AccessDenied Yes, I do specify it, and yes, it shows them correctly in LogCat.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
TextView item_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
item_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitle()));
```